# Postgres won't connect to server in Ruby on Rails app using c9.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, cloud9-ide

A few days ago, I was able to successfully install Postgresql and create/migrate my databases over from SQLite (in preparation for deploying my Rails 4 app)...or so I thought.

I restarted my server, but when I try to access my app, I get this error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad
could not connect to server: Connection refused 
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket 
"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've seen several similar answered questions on SO, but they all involve Macs. Since i'm using the Cloud 9 IDE instead, I thought there might be differences (for instance, the mentions of `localhost` are probably not relevant, because that's not how I access the app currently on c9.io.)

According to the answers on the other questions, I tried this in my terminal:

```
sudo ps auxw | grep post
```

which gave me:

```
ubuntu    2527  0.0  0.0  10552   888 pts/5    S+   15:21   0:00 grep --color=auto post
```

then I tried:

```
sudo find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432 -ls
```

and I got:

```
5286    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           26 May 11 15:13 /var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432 -> /private/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
5183    0 srwxrwxrwx   1 postgres postgres        0 May 10 22:18 /run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

yamilethmedina@wheels_registration:~/workspace (master|MERGING) $ psql
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Here is the full trace of my server:

```
Started GET "/" for 12.43.117.2 at 2015-05-11 16:35:48 +0000

PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in  `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.1.6)  lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:388:in `check_pending!'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6)   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.8ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.9ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (45.7ms)
```

My entire github repo just in case:
https://github.com/yamilethmedina/wheels_registration.git

Comment: it doesn't look like postgresql is running.  Perhaps it is not set to auto start. Try `sudo service postgresql start`  and see if it comes back.   if that works than do `sudo update-rc.d postgresql defaults`  to make it start at boot if you want

Comment: @Doon it turns out that postgresql hadn't started and the app now loads, so thanks! however, when I put in `sudo update-rc.d postgresql defaults` after starting it, it says `System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/postgresql already exist.` I doubt that means auto-start is already active, because it obviously didn't start running when I booted the server.

Comment: i'm having the same error. but my postgresql is already running: **sudo service postgresql status**     `9.4/main (port 5432): online`

Comment: postgresql isn't shutdown properly it won't start the next time..if the start stop links are there, that does mean it should autostart. but if there was a pid or the like laying around from unclean shutdown that could have been the problem.

Comment: @Deema Unless it is the exact same issue as this, you should probably open another questions. but how is app configured to talk., via unix socket or via ip?  firewall in place etc...

Comment: @Doon how do I make sure that it shuts down properly? Do I have to quit postgresql in the terminal every day or so while i'm on the test server? Does just allowing the test server to shut off automatically after a certain period of time without using it cause postgresql to shut down improperly (that's what I did last time?) and this problem would be solved when I deploy to a permanent server?

Comment: if the vm shuts down normally it should just postgresql down normally. I am not saying that it did shutdown abnormally but that if it did that can cause it to not start at boot since if thinks it is already running it will not start.

Comment: @Doon if you make your comments into an answer, i'll select it as the best one and upvote it. :)

Comment: @Doon thank you. I managed to finally fix it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't look like postgresql is running. Perhaps it is not set to auto start. One reason for this can be if postgresql wasn't cleanly shutdown on the last run, and leaves a pid file laying around.

Try

```
  sudo service postgresql start
```

and see if it comes back, and just make sure that you shut the vm down (so the stop scripts can run) as opposed to just powering it off.

Comment: How do I shut down the vm? I usually just close the window so that the server stays running but I doubt that's ideal.

Comment: are you using your own vm with it? or running on theirs?  (I don't use cloud9, so I am not 100% sure how it works)

Comment: It's their own entire vm environment

Comment: Ahh. Well in that case you will need to talk to them. My guess is that the instances just get killed. After inactivity  with SQLite this doesn't matter but it will make Postgres grumpy.  I would stop the Postgres instance when you are done  safer that way ( or just use SQLite for dev).  You should not have this issue in production.

Comment: to shut it down, I would use `sudo service postgresql stop`, correct?

Comment: Yes that will shut it down safely.  And when you need it again just start it up.